# bashing into 25 knots

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can you please help me understand what the meaning of the highlighted sentence mean? It is part of a travel diary. I am leaving the whole paragraph here so that you can get the big picture.

> *Altered course so I would get as far upwind from the squall as I could. **But bashing into 25 knots makes it 30 knots** so I had a pretty wild ride for about an hour. At its closest point I had lightening about a mile away while going through a squall. At 3-something this morning I was able to get back on course and go back to sleep. Over the night I passed about ten ships.*

Answer (score 3):

First, some definitions:

- A [**knot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_(unit)) is a unit of speed, equal to one nautical mile per hour. 1 knot is approximately 1.15 regular or "statute" miles per hour. (This is a separate meaning from the more common usage of the word *knot*, which is the thing you tie with a rope. The meanings are historically related: ships used to measure speed by letting out a long rope with *knots* tied at certain intervals, and counting how many *knots* went overboard in a certain amount of time.)
- A [**squall**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squall) is a short-lived wind storm, often with heavy rain.
- [**Upwind**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windward_and_leeward) is the direction from which the wind is blowing.
- **To bash (into)** something is to slam into it forcefully. One might talk about "waves bashing into the rocks" or, as in this paragraph, a ship bashing into the waves in "heavy seas" (a body of water with tall and chaotic waves).

The author, presumably a sailor, is saying that the squall had 25 knots of wind (wind blowing at 25 knots). The sailor sailed upwind to stay away from the squall. It seems the boat is [capable of moving upwind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_sail) at 5 knots, which would make the *apparent* wind 30 knots. Near a squall with heavy seas, this would indeed make for a "wild ride."